# Configure JAAS in embedded Jetty with CXF and Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, cxf, jaas

I am trying to setup a CXF + Spring + embedded jetty with basic authentication relying on JAAS and i am having problems to connect all pieces.

I want to use the CXF JAASLoginInterceptor that looks very easy to configure so my service definition in the ApplicationContext would look like

```
<jaxws:endpoint address="/soapService">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="serviceImpl" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxws:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="authenticationInterceptor"/>
    </jaxws:inInterceptors>
</jaxws:endpoint>

<bean id="authenticationInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.security.JAASLoginInterceptor">
   <property name="contextName" value="jaasContext"/>
   <property name="roleClassifier" value="ROLE_"/>
</bean>
```

As the doc states: "The JAAS authenticator is configured with the name of the JAAS login context (the one usually specified in the JAAS configuration resource which the server is aware of)"

How can i setup that "JAAS configuration resource" in the most basic way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end it is very easy to do it. The only thing you need is place a file with login modules configuration on the classpath and set the system property "java.security.auth.login.config" pointing to that file.

e.g. a file to enable a property file based authentication:

jaasContext {
    org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jaas.spi.PropertyFileLoginModule optional
    file="src/main/resources/credentials.props"; 
};

Note that the contextName in the CXF interceptor is same as in the jaas config file.